# Segmentation Fault in PHP7

Tags: magento2, php-7, magento-2.0

We have encountered this weird issue with PHP 7.0. We are running Magento2's indexers on PHP 7.0 and have different outcomes on different environments.
If we use CentOS, and get PHP 7.0 from either [Remi's Repo](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/) or [Webtatic Repo](https://webtatic.com/projects/yum-repository/), we get a **Segmentation Fault** as follows:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
zend_mm_alloc_small (size=<optimized out>, bin_num=<optimized out>, heap=<optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/php-7.0.1RC1/Zend/zend_alloc.c:1291
1291                    heap->free_slot[bin_num] = p->next_free_slot;
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install openssl-libs-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.1.x86_64
(gdb) backtrace
#0  zend_mm_alloc_small (size=<optimized out>, bin_num=<optimized out>, heap=<optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/php-7.0.1RC1/Zend/zend_alloc.c:1291
#1  zend_mm_alloc_heap (size=<optimized out>, heap=<optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/php-7.0.1RC1/Zend/zend_alloc.c:1358
#2  _emalloc (size=3, size@entry=32) at /usr/src/debug/php-7.0.1RC1/Zend/zend_alloc.c:2442
#3  0x0000555555666840 in zend_string_alloc (persistent=0, len=4) at /usr/src/debug/php-7.0.1RC1/Zend/zend_string.h:121
#4  php_pcre_replace_impl (pce=pce@entry=0x555555e76e40, subject_str=subject_str@entry=0x7fffd72fec68, subject=subject@entry=0x7fffd72fec80 "TypeId", subject_len=subject_len@entry=6, replace_val=replace_val@entry=0x7fffd2a393b0,
    is_callable_replace=is_callable_replace@entry=0, limit=<optimized out>, limit@entry=-1, replace_count=replace_count@entry=0x7fffffff7d5c) at /usr/src/debug/php-7.0.1RC1/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c:1217
```

But, if we use a compiled PHP7 version, there is no error. We also tried with a vagrant box configured with Ubuntu 14.0 and PHP 7.0.0 from ppa:ondrej/php-7.0 and no issues there either.

Any ideas why this error occurs when using these specific repos?

**Updated**
with 7.0.1 stack trace is different:

```
`Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffded34620 in ?? ()
#0  0x00007fffded34620 in ?? ()
#1  0x00005555557db82b in execute_ex (ex=<optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/php-7.0.1/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:414
#2  0x000055555578ddd9 in dtrace_execute_ex (execute_data=<optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/php-7.0.1/Zend/zend_dtrace.c:83
```

Comment: First try 7.0.1, released yesterday.

Comment: We tried with PHP 7.0.1RC1 with same results. Will try with 7.0.1.

Comment: We just tried with php-7.0.1-1.el7.remi.x86_64 and still segfault :(

Comment: I think it will be better to file an upstream bug on https://bugs.php.net/ but with a simple reproducer... (could be related to dtrace feature or security build flags used by default for RPM)

Answer (score 1):

Please see this link from Magento forum:

https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2/PHP-7-Segmentation-Fault-CentOS-7-x/td-p/25031

And this from official repo:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2750

During some local tests I've replicated this problem (Ubuntu 14.04 with ppa:ondrej/php-7.0), and the worse part is that "segmentation fault" would keep the indexer as "processing" (make sense as it was not finished successfully), we had to change data table (indexer_state) and manually fixed those values before re-run the re-index.

Seems like Magento 2 has not "fully" supported PHP7?

Comment: PHP7 issues have been fixed in [tag 2.0.1](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.0.1) Please have a look and let us know if your issue has been fixed.